# Pandas groupby with condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

suppose I have the following df:

```
| name | age |
| ---  | ----|
| John | 8   |
| John | 2   |
| John | 4   |
| Anna | 8   |
| Anna | 2   |
| Anna | 4   |
```

I want to create the following df (how many kids with same name there are below 5 years old and beyond):

```
| name | age < 5 | age > 5 |
| ---  | ----    | -----   |
| John | 2       | 1       |
| Anna | 2       | 1       |
```

I suppose I should use `df.groupby()` but I can't manage to think of a way to apply this condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['name'], np.where(df['age'] > 5, 'age>5', 'age=<5'))
print (df)
col_0  age=<5  age>5
name                
Anna        2      1
John        2      1
```

Or:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['age'] > 5).rename(columns={False:'age>5',True:'age<=5'})
print (df)
age   age>5  age<=5
name               
Anna      2       1
John      2       1
```

Last for column `name` use:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to compute the conditional column, `groupby` then `unstack`:

```
(
    df.assign(cond=np.where(df.age.gt(5), "age>5", "age<5"))
    .groupby(["name", "cond"])
    .size()
    .unstack()
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

```
name    age<5  age>5
Anna    2   1
John    2   1
```

Comment: In this way, how can I keep the label of the column 'name'?

Comment: Oh in that case get rid of the index=None in rename_axis

Comment: Yeah that works, but now I get two levels of labels: 0 - age>5, age<5; 1 - name. How can I put them all in the same level?

Comment: You can add a reset_ index